# Having fast refresh on materialized views having virtual columns

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I wanted a Materialized View with fast refresh (update on the contained tables update).
The materialized view query is something like:

```
SELECT T1.CODE, T2.NAME
FROM T1

UNION ALL

SELECT T2.CODE, T3.NAME
FROM T2, T3
WHERE T2.ID = T3.ID
```

It appears that in case of using `UNION ALL` I should add `ROWID` to achieve fast refresh.

Adding `ROWID` is ok for the first part, but for the second part it can not be added as it has a join.

It seems there are 2 options to overcome this:

1. Adding a redundant column for `NAME` on `T2` and remove the `T3` from query.
2. Adding a virtual column containing a function that selects name from `T3` like

   NAME NVARCHAR2(4000) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("SCHEMA"."GET_NAME_FROM_OTHER_TABLE"("ID"))

According to this link: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php
it says:

> Materialized views that access the virtual column must be fully refreshed.

and

> If it refers to a deterministic user-defined function, it cannot be used as a partitioning key column.

Could I still have a Fast Refresh option on the materialized view using Solution 2?

Comment: function that uses data from another table cannot be deterministic - then no.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505020/oracle-how-to-create-a-materialized-view-with-fast-refresh-and-joins might help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT T1.CODE, T2.NAME, T1.ROWID as ROWID_T1, NULL as ROWID_T2, NULL as ROWID_T3 
FROM T1

UNION ALL

SELECT T2.CODE, T3.NAME, NULL as ROWID_T1, T2.ROWID as ROWID_T2, T3.ROWID as ROWID_T3 
FROM T2, T3
WHERE T2.ID = T3.ID
```

Maybe you have to use `CAST(NULL AS ROWID) AS ROWID_T2` in order to get proper data type in first query.